# for an html document, pageYoffset value in JavaScript differs from normal scrolling when clicked on an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a html document with table of contents and  anchor tags or links are present to the document headers for easy navigation.I added a scroll event to call a function where pageYoffset value is required.It works fine when scrolling through the document.I get the current pageYoffset value.
 But when i click on any anchor tag in the table of contents the pageYoffset value differs from the value obtained when scrolling to a particular header.

For example:
consider the following text as a html document

> **table of contents:**
>
> 1. Intro
> 2. prerequsites
> 3. conclusion
>
> *1.Intro:*    some text under 1st header

1.intro is an header in the html document.When i scroll down till i see  1.intro,I get some offset value. But instead of scrolling when i click on 1.intro in table of contents, the pageYoffset value is different for the same header.This is causing issue in my function.

So, can anyone help to me to get current scrolled value from top evne when clicking on anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved as i found The main root cause is that the html document height is changing dynamically due to some expanding feature and so the offset stored previously changes and while comparing it with old offset if fails.